# Sum() slows down my query

Tags: mysql

I am using sum() inside case statement. But this slows down my query. Is there any other way for this. This is the query. Please help me.

```
SELECT (SUM(PRI_INS_AGING) + SUM(SEC_INS_AGING) + SUM(TER_INS_AGING)) AS INS_AGING,SUM(PAT_AGING) AS PAT_AGING FROM
                (SELECT 
        CASE WHEN L.RESP_PARTY =1 AND VP.STATUS IN(3,5) AND VP.PRIMARY_PAID =0 AND VP.PRIMARY_PENDING >0 AND C.PRIMARY_PAYER_ID >0 AND C.HIDEN=0 THEN SUM(L.AMOUNT) ELSE 0 END AS PRI_INS_AGING,
        CASE WHEN L.RESP_PARTY =2 AND VP.STATUS IN(6,7,5) AND VP.SECONDARY_PAID =0 AND VP.SECONDARY_PENDING >0 AND VP.PRIMARY_PENDING <=0 AND C.SECONDARY_PAYER_ID >0 AND C.HIDEN=0 THEN SUM(L.AMOUNT) ELSE 0 END AS SEC_INS_AGING,
        CASE WHEN L.RESP_PARTY =3 AND VP.STATUS IN(8,9,5) AND VP.TERTIARY_PAID =0 AND VP.TERTIARY_PENDING >0 AND VP.PRIMARY_PENDING <=0 AND VP.SECONDARY_PENDING <=0 AND C.TERTIARY_PAYER_ID >0 AND C.HIDEN=0 THEN SUM(L.AMOUNT) ELSE 0 END AS TER_INS_AGING,
        CASE WHEN L.RESP_PARTY =4 THEN SUM(L.AMOUNT) ELSE 0 END AS PAT_AGING
        FROM VISIT_PROCEDURE VP
        JOIN CLAIM C 
        ON (C.CLAIM_ID = VP.CLAIM_ID AND C.CLINIC_ID = VP.CLINIC_ID)
        JOIN LEDGER L
        ON (L.CLAIM_ID = L.CLAIM_ID AND VP.CLINIC_ID = L.CLINIC_ID)
        WHERE C.CLINIC_ID = 34847 AND L.TYPE IN(1,8,9,10,11) AND L.ACTIVE=1 
        GROUP BY VP.PROCEDURE_ID,L.TYPE,L.RESP_PARTY,L.ACTIVE)T1
```

Thanks
Sunil

Comment: How are we supposed to run your query to see the profiling? Every "query problem" on this site (had you searched, you'd see it) has the output of `EXPLAIN` posted. Otherwise, good luck debugging your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without extra dissecting your SQL, look into your join on LEDGER... you have it doing the CLAIM_ID on the same value...

```
JOIN LEDGER L   ON L.CLAIM_ID = L.CLAIM_ID AND VP.CLINIC_ID = L.CLINIC_ID
```

Should the "L.Claim_ID" be joined to a "VP.Claim_ID"??? or something else?

Ok, so with a little bit of time, I came up with this... I would swap the query around some.  In addition, make sure you have an index ON your CLAIM table on Clinic_ID AND Hiden.  Also, your inner query is breaking down the SUM of distinct parts of insurance claims, yet you are not doing anything ELSE with them except summing them in the outer.  I would change to just sum ONCE at the outer for the given conditions

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      SUM( IF(   L.RESP_PARTY = 1 
             AND VP.STATUS IN(3,5) 
             AND VP.PRIMARY_PAID = 0 
             AND VP.PRIMARY_PENDING > 0 
             AND C.PRIMARY_PAYER_ID > 0, L.AMOUNT, 0 )

           +
           IF(   L.RESP_PARTY = 2 
             AND VP.STATUS IN(6,7,5) 
             AND VP.SECONDARY_PAID = 0 
             AND VP.SECONDARY_PENDING > 0 
             AND VP.PRIMARY_PENDING <= 0 
             AND C.SECONDARY_PAYER_ID > 0, L.AMOUNT, 0 )

           +
           IF(   L.RESP_PARTY = 3 
             AND VP.STATUS IN(8,9,5) 
             AND VP.TERTIARY_PAID = 0 
             AND VP.TERTIARY_PENDING > 0 
             AND VP.PRIMARY_PENDING <= 0 
             AND VP.SECONDARY_PENDING <= 0 
             AND C.TERTIARY_PAYER_ID > 0, L.AMOUNT, 0 ) ) as INS_AGING,

      SUM( IF( L.RESP_PARTY = 4, L.AMOUNT, 0 )) as PAT_AGING

   FROM 
      CLAIM C
         JOIN VISIT_PROCEDURE VP
            ON C.CLAIM_ID = VP.CLAIM_ID
           AND C.CLINIC_ID = VP.CLINIC_ID

             JOIN LEDGER L
                ON VP.CLINIC_ID = L.CLINIC_ID
               AND VP.CLAIM_ID = L.CLAIM_ID
               AND L.TYPE IN ( 1, 8, 9, 10, 11 ) 
               AND L.ACTIVE = 1 
   WHERE 
          C.CLINIC_ID = 34847 
      AND C.HIDEN = 0
```

Comment: Hi DRapp  Thanks for your consideration.it really helped me a lot.thanks once again for spending your valuable time.

Comment: @Sunil, no problem... but did it work... Also, as a newbie, as you post questions and someone offers a solution that best helps solve your problem, it's good to give them credit by clicking the checkbox to the left of their answer to let others know a solution is done and others can move on to other questions that might still need assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to get the SUM() of your data, I don't see you getting it any other way. That said, this is pretty complex and you might benefit from breaking it down into a stored proc and splitting the calculations up into stages.

Btw what does slow mean here? 1 second rather than 0.001? Or, 2 minutes?

Comment: Hi Brian                                                                      Thanks for your reply.Actually this query is taking about 40 seconds .It slows down when my ledger table has more records.Otherwise it will only take below 10 second.And that is affordable for me.Is there way to tackle that other than stored proc.

Comment: Do you have indexes?  If not, adding indexes will definitely help you. You could look at the EXPLAIN plan and see if your query is using them.